Detect precision loss in numpy floats
If the difference between two numbers is too large, the smallest number will be "lost". Does this raise any flag that I can check?
In float32, the significant has 24 binary digits, therefore if the difference between numbers is greater than 10^7.2, the smaller number will be lost. Obviously, I could use decimal or float64, but this code is just an example:
# Max 7.2 decimal digits of difference

## First experiment:
np.seterr(all='warn')
n1 = np.pow(np.float32(10), 9)
n2 = np.float32(1)

print("n1:", n1, "n2:", n2, "n1+n2:", n1+n2, "n1+n2==n1:", n1+n2==n1)
# n1: 1000000000.0 n2: 1.0 n1+n2: 1000000000.0 n1+n2==n1: True

## Second experiment
n1 = np.pow(np.float32(10), 9)
total = np.float32(0)
n2 = n1

for i in tqdm(range(10**9)):
    total += 1
    n2 += 1

print("n1:", n1, "n2:", n2, "total:", total, "n1+total:", n1+total)
# n1: 1000000000.0 n2: 1000000000.0 total: 16777216.0 n1+total: 1016777200.0

Is it possible to detect if this error happened? How is this kind of error called and how can I search for more information?

Your sample code shows how to detect it; if n1+n2 == n1 or n1+n2 == n2, the smaller number had no effect on the addition result. What more are you looking for? Further, why do you care about this particular case and not the case where, say, only the top bit of n2 affected the result and the bottom 23 bits had no effect and were lost? What difference does it make to your application?

This is just a rounding error causing a loss of precision. The result of n1+n2 is rounded to 24 bits.
These happen all the time, not just with addition. 1/3 is not representable as a binary number regardless of digits, so it's always rounded. Because it happens on pretty much every operation, trying to detect every instance of it is not feasible.
Instead, the usual advice it to take one step back and use a better numerical algorithm, where the rounding error does not cause problems for the intended application. In this simple case, the solution is equally simple: use an integral type for integral addition. More complex cases have more complex solutions; trying to summarize that here would be foolish. This field is called numerical analysis, and it's a mix of math and computer science.
